# Why Usercontrol show javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, user-controls

Work on Asp.net web page.I have a user control,need to use this control several times on my page.Bellow image show this javascript error.How to use user control multiple time in same page.

Page syntax:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register src="ucTest.ascx" tagname="ucTest" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <uc1:ucTest ID="ucTest1" runat="server" />
        <uc1:ucTest ID="ucTest2" runat="server" />
        <uc1:ucTest ID="ucTest3" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

User control syntax:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ucTest.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.ucTest" %>



<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFrom"  />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var txtFrom = document.getElementById("<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>");
    var txtTo = document.getElementById("<%= txtTo.ClientID %>");

    txtFrom.onblur = function () {
        debugger;
        txtTo.value = txtFrom.value;
        alert(txtTo);
    }
</script>
```

javascript error :
[image]

Comment: Your script should at the bottom of page or after control declaration.

Comment: Amit, thanks for your reply.After put the javascript on bottom of usercontrol it's working.But one new problem arise values are not set on specified controls.Need information why not value update on exact control.

Comment: Are you assigning value at code behind also? Chances are that it might overwrite. Check onblur compatibility for browser version.

Comment: Amit ,i dont assign value at code behind,i set value on javascript,which function help me to handle this situation.what to do .....will you plz provide some syntax.

Comment: Amit,please my update user control syntax.

Comment: Provide complete source code aspx and user control too. How many times you have used this usercontrol on the page? It seems that variables getting overwritten in process.